# Parameterize the schema in a strongly-typed ADO.NET TableAdapter

Tags: ado.net, dataset, strongly-typed-dataset, tableadapter

I'm trying to build a strongly-typed dataset in ADO.Net and am having a little trouble with one aspect of the TableAdapters.

My query looks like

```
SELECT *
FROM testdict.ModuleVariable
WHERE Module = ?
```

My problem revolves around the testdict part.  We use several different schemas to access our data (because of a multiplexed Sybase IQ instance).  How can I parameterize the schema portion of this query?

I've tried:

```
SELECT *
FROM ?.ModuleVariable
WHERE Module = ?
```

but to no avail.  My current mindset is that I may have to inherit the TableAdapter and parameterize the schema manually but I am hoping there is a nicer solution!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **First of all you won't be able to achieve this in design-time by simply adding a select query. You cannot parametrize the schema.**

However there's a solution for this.Here's how you can do that.

1.) Drag and drop the table into your typed-dataset designer which will **create a typed-data-table** for the table and the **table-adapter to access database table**. table adapter is aware of the schema of the data-table.

2.) Now **create a stored-procedure** in your database that takes **two arguments**. one is the **schema of the table** [?.ModuleVariable] and other would be your **where clause** or maybe anytihng you may want as criteria. You can create overloads of this as you wish. This stored-procedure will then construct the sql query based on the arguments and execute it on the database. This will **return the result-set to calling table-adapter**.

3.) From the design-view **Add a method to table-adapter** which will fetch results from the stored-procedure. **Make sure that the schema of results exactly meets the schema of the associated data-table**.

4.) Now from the code you can create an instance of the table adapter and call the method which in turn will call your stored-procedure and **return you with the data-table filled in with results**.

Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

You can overload or add a new function to the table adapter, because they are defined as partial classes. This new function would have the schema name as a parameter. For example, Fill(table As (tableName), schemaName As String). Here's how I'd do it:

1. Create a new file and name it (dataSetName).(whatever_you_like).vb.
2. At the top put Namespace (dataSetName)TableAdapters.
3. Use an Import statement to easily access the tables in the data set. Imports (solutionName).(dataSetName).
4. Define the new function. This example function is a bit simplified, but I guess it will be enough for you to get the idea.

Partial Class (tableName)TableAdapter
  Public Overloads Function Fill( _
    table As (tableName), _
    schemaName As String) As Integer

```
Dim args() As String = {schemaName, table.TableName}
Dim selectCmdText As String = "SELECT * FROM {0}.{1}"
selectCmdText = String.Format(selectCmdText, args)

Connection.Open()
Dim selectCmd As New MySqlCommand(selectCmdText, Connection)    
Dim adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter(selectCmd)

Dim returnValue As Integer = 0
returnValue = adapter.Fill(table)

Connection.Close()

Return returnValue
```

End Function
End Class

Kind regards,
Carlos Mallen